# Too much time for MPI comm merge operation

Tags: mpi, openmpi

In my sample MPI code, I'm trying to merge two groups of processes (parent and child) after MPI_Comm_spawn using

```
MPI_Intercomm_merge(intercomm, 0, &intracomm);
```

where 'intercomm' is the inter-communicator handle returned from spawn operation and 'intracomm' is the merged intra-communicator.

Here I try to measure the time taken for this merge operation using

```
MPI_Wtime();
```

For 24 MPI processes, it measures 0.93 seconds compared to MPI_Comm_spawn which just takes 0.14 seconds.

Is MPI_Comm_merge operation a heavy in terms of computation time? I am not sure if this is weird or normal.

Comment: How exactly did you measure? On which process? Did you do a barrier before? Maybe it is just an effect of an imbalance. Also an [mcve] would help.

Comment: Intercommunicator merge is an infrequently used (during the lifetime of an MPI application, that is) and expensive operation. As long as the rest of the operations are fast, I wouldn't bother with it taking a bit longer.